# onchange handler prevents href method from being called

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a simple form with one input field.  The input field has an `onchange` event handler.
If I enter a value in the field, and then directly click the done button so that the input field does not lose focus, my `onchange` handler gets called, but my href method does not.

Any ideas why?  I've spent hours trying to figure this out and have not had any luck so far.

Below is the sample code:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script language="Javascript">
      function validateInput()
      {
         alert("validateInput()");
        return true;
      }

      function setEdited()
      {
         alert("setEdited()");
         return true;
      }
      </script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <form name="my_form" method="post" action="next_page.html">
         <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="5">
            <tr>
              <td>field 1</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="field_1" size="20" value="abc" onchange="setEdited()"/></td>
            </tr>
         </table>
         <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" >
            <tr>
               <td align="right" nowrap >&nbsp;<a href="javascript:validateInput()">Done</a>        </td>
               <td align="right" nowrap >&nbsp;<a href="javascript:window.close()" >Cancel</a>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to call those methods when you click the link. href is an  attribute that takes a url. 
href attribute isn't an event handler. Try the onclick attribute.

```
<td align="right" nowrap="nowrap" > <a onclick="validateInput()">Done</a> </td>
<td align="right" nowrap="nowrap" > <a onclick="window.close()" >Cancel</a> </td>
```

Comment: Get rid of the `javascript:` part of the cilck handler.  Not required.